# Arduino YUN real time control

Tags: arduino-yun

I have a very specific problem, exactly with real time control. For example I try to write an application where I can edit min or max temperature that after reaching it , I will receive SMS with message. I'm wondering how to edit variables "on-the-fly" because, as I know Arduino IDE use it own libraries not this from C/C++, and I don't know how to get to SD card in Arduino too. Can someone help ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

the SD card is at /mnt/sd/ . you should consider reading the yun tutorials [here](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Bridge) before going further, the ability to send and receive data is at the heart of the yun design.